# Sort Product Collection By Event Date Custom field

Tags: magento2, product-sorting

I have created Events type products using Magento Virtual Product.

A custom product attribute "**event_date**" has created to mark the event as **Active** or **Past** event.

If the **event_date** field value is a past date then  I showed a label "**Past Event**" with the Product.

**We need to show the all active events first then all past events in product listing page**

**I successfully did that** by setting 
Product **Listing Sort** = "**event_date**"

( From **admin** ***->*** **STORES** ***->*** **Catalog** ***->*** **Storefront** ***->*** ***Product Listing Sort by*** configuration)

**I also set default sort order to "DESC" using catalog_category_view.xml.**

After setting default sort order to "DESC", All Active Events are now coming first then Past events in product listing page.

**Now the issue is:**

**I need to implement another second sorting, So the Active event will be listed by "ASC" order.**

For Example :

Event :**DemoA** , Event Date = January 24, 2019

Event :**DemoB** , Event Date = January 10, 2019

Here both DemoA, DemoB events are active events as the "event_date" value is not past date but since I set 
the default sort order to "DESC"  Event **DemoA** (*January 24, 2019*) comes first then Event **DemoB**(*January 10, 2019* ) comes.

How can I show  Event **DemoB**(*January 10, 2019* ) first then  Event **DemoA**(*January 24, 2019*)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using a plugin for **Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer** and modifying the Sort Order using [CASE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) as described below.

1) Declare the plugin in **di.xml**
under **/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/**

2) create **Layer.php** under ***/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/***

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class Layer
{


    protected $timezone;

    public function __construct(    
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone
    ) {     
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
    }

     public function afterGetProductCollection($subject, $collection) 
     {
       $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');              
       $collection->getSelect()->order(
       new \Zend_Db_Expr(
        "CASE WHEN event_date >= '".$currentDate."' THEN event_date ELSE '9999-12-31' END ASC,
         CASE WHEN event_date <  '".$currentDate."' THEN event_date ELSE NULL END DESC")
       );       
       return $collection;
    }   

}
```